# Facebook Javascript SDK: Check if the user has liked more than one facebook pages

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im trying to create an application where it will check whether the user has liked the necessary facebook pages(in this case the user needs to like two facebook pages) before further options becomes available

this is how i tried to do it but i cant seem to make it work

```
var lcount = "0";
        FB.api('/me/likes/<?php echo $tabid1;?>', function(likes) {
        console.log(likes);
            if(likes.data.length === 1){
            console.log("like 1 insert");
               lcount++;
            }
            else{

            }

            FB.api('/me/likes/<?php echo $tabid2;?>', function(likes2) {
            console.log(likes2);
                if(likes2.data.length === 1){
                console.log("like 2 insert");
                    lcount++;
                }
                else{

                }
            });

        console.log(lcount);

        });
```

with this code if the user has liked both facebook pages

my console.log(lcount) result only shows 1 instead of 2

is there a way to solve my problem using facebook javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

just get all of user liked pages and crawl them. You'll need the user permission "user_likes".

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=likes

You will get something like:

```
{
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "category": "Software",
        "name": "PhpStorm",
        "created_time": "2013-10-30T13:20:59+0000",
        "id": "1415454902003639"
      },
      {
        "category": "Actor/director",
        "name": "Kevin Spacey",
        "created_time": "2013-09-21T10:00:01+0000",
        "id": "11177446882"
      },
      {
        "category": "Video game",
        "name": "EverQuest Next Europe",
        "created_time": "2013-08-02T21:28:03+0000",
        "id": "461548750597327"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can look with the ID if it is a fanpage.

Hope that helps you!

Best regards,
Jurik